# Is it unnecessary to unmount twice?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet, usb-connection-mode, mount, ebook-reader

My Android 4.0.4 tablet (Onyx Boox i86) mounts the internal and external SD cards as real read/write drives (not MTP) on my computer. In order to do this it goes into "USB mode" where the tablet's OS no longer has access to the storage while the computer is accessing it.

Before unplugging the tablet, I usually do "Eject" in the desktop OS X/GNU/Windows file manager, and then click "Turn off USB storage" on the display of the tablet.

Is it alright to:

1. Just eject the drives on the desktop, and then physically plug out the cable?
2. Just click "Turn off USB Storage" on the tablet display and then plug out the cable?

Comment: The "secure removal" or ejection, when issued from a device whose USB ports provide some voltage (as a computer), serves the purpose of cutting out the voltage before unplugging the peripheral. This is done to avoid electromagnetic spikes that could possibly damage eventual data. In fact, ejecting a device does not kill an eventual data transfer, and instead your computer will tell you to either wait until the end of the operation, or to kill the process which transfers said data. So, in my opinion, only the first one of the two possibilities is needed.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: Because I'm not fully certain of those info, and would like some of the other respectable members to review them. The behaviour I described above is valid for Microsoft OSes, but I've no proof that Un*x does the same.